# Restrict access to images in bucket to authenticated users

Tags: angular, authorization, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Looking for instructions on how to setup Google Cloud Storage bucket with images that only authenticated users can access.

Our application uses Firstore and Cloud Storage. We store images in GCS buckets which we do not want publicly visible on the NET.
We have setup storage rules

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

We have also configured the bucket in our Firebase config settings.
We then use the storage API to getDownloadURL() for the target path.
This works and we are able to see the images. However, if we copy the Image URL from the page and go to another browser (that is not logged in) that browser is able to download the image.

Question: what is the correct (and most efficient) way to configure and access a GCS bucket such that only authenticated users authenticated using Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword() can view the images.

Here is what we do currently (Angular and AngularFire)

```
// Assumes storage is an instance of the AngularFireStorage service
this.storage.getDownloadURL('/thumbs/imagename.jpg')
  .subscribe(path => {
     this.imgSrc = path;
});
```

As described above, the resulting path is public and the above process is very slow - images take a long time to appear on the screen.

I am guessing this is not the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

The content behind a download URLs can always be viewed by anyone who simply has the URL.  You can't change this behavior.  If you don't want any unauthorized content to be served from your bucket, then don't generate any download URLs.  You will have to force all access to the bucket through the provided client SDKs in conjunction with the Firebase Authentication SDK.

Comment: Thanks Doug - I think what I am asking is for details on how to do that. As I mentioned we have been struggling with this for sometime and public access to the images is a deal breaker. We are only generating the URL's currently so that something is visible. We are really struggling with the docs - if you have a resource that lays this out for us - I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think there is anything to know that isn't covered in the product documentation.  The bottom line is that you won't be able to generate a URL to put in a img tag.  The JavaScript doesn't have the ability to download the image data to an element on screen like you have with Firebase-UI on Android and iOS.  The available methods a reference can be see in the API docs.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference

Answer (score 0):

As Doug said, you would have to use the client SDK to accomplish that, depending on the level of control you need you can choose one of the options listed on the official documentation [1] and to only let authenticated users have access with Firebase Authentication SDK [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/

[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security

Comment: Thanks Ricardo - as I mentioned in my OP we have already configured the rules as per the second link - does not have an effect. The first link is just to high level to really help - looking for something that can help us with the details.